# Using a "variable" in Excel

Tags: excel, variables, matrix, excel-formula

I have a pretty large Excel with alot of data, spred across multiple sheets.
So what i'm wondering is if their is anyway to make a cell act like a variable. Not really sure how to explain it.

Let's say I have a matrix in **Sheet3** that goes from **A1:D20** and I wan't to use that matrix in a **VLOOKUP** formula in **Sheet1**.

Then I would have to write `=VLOOKUP(A1;'Sheet3'!A1:D20;2;FALSE)`

Can I instead make a cell in **Sheet1** reference that matrix? For example if I put **='Sheet3'!A1:D20** in **C1** so that I would only have to write `=VLOOKUP(A1;C1;2;FALSE)`

I have been trying to find the answer to this question but without any luck. So now i'm mostly just wondering if this is even possible.

Comment: I *think* you are looking for `INDIRECT`, but be aware that it comes with its own set of problems. You may also want to investigate named ranges

Comment: Thank you @cybernetic.nomad the named ranges will atleast make it easier. I will look abit more into `INDIRECT` but it doesen't really seem to do the trick for me, but I will look into it some more.

Comment: Actually `INDIRECT`seems to be what I was looking for and together with named rages I'm getting almost exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the `Indirect()` worksheet function. **Indirect**'s definition is as follows:

> *Returns the **reference** specified by a **text string**.*

Where **reference** would be the cell reference you are wanting to 
obtain, and **text string** is the *textual representation* of your **reference**.

Essentially, Let's say your cell `C1` contained the textual reference: `Sheet1!A1:D20`. You can then use the `Indirect()` formula to get this reference as such:

```
=INDIRECT($C$1)
```

---

You can also create a *dynamically-named range*. You can access this menu by:

> Formula Tab > Name Manager > New

You can name this range anything that isn't already reserved by Excel, so in this example we will name it `lookupRng`.

You can make this change dynamically - for example, when the number of rows in your range changes, by using something like:

```
=OFFSET(Sheet3!$A$1:$D$1,0,0,COUNTA(Sheet3!$A:$A),1)
```

Which could be called doing: `=VLOOKUP(A1;lookupRng;2;FALSE)`

Answer (score 2):

Would naming the Range help?

Select the range you desire and assign a Name to it, for example: "Matrix"
in the Name Box as shown on the picture below.

[image]

Then you can use this name in your VLOOKUP formula.

```
=VLOOKUP(A1;Matrix;2;FALSE)
```

Comment: You can press F3 while writing your formula and it will propose you all your Names you have assigned this way.